# Github Identity provider does not appear on log in dialog

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I setup GitHub as an identity provider using the instructions found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-github).

When I try to log into my site GitHub does not appear on the list of providers.
I did the same for Microsoft and Google and both appear on the login dialog.  Why not GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please enable Github IDP for the user flow policy you are trying to sign in/signup

[image]